# How to create a 160x600 size ad unit in the new Windows Dev Center?

Tags: windows-store-apps

I had developed a windows store app last year and used Microsoft PubCenter to create a 160x600 size ad unit. I am developing another app now. PubCenter does not appear to allow creating any more ad units. It seems one has to create a new ad unit from dev.windows.com -> Dashboard -> Monetization -> Monetize with ads. I went there and it gives me this UI:
[image]

where is the option to select the ad size? I created an ad, and oddly enough I can't see its properties on dev.windows.com. To see the ad properties I have to go to pubcenter and over there it shows the ad size as 300x250. So here are my questions:
1. Does the latest ad platform not support 160x600 size ads?
2. Is it ok if I use the old ad unit with the new app (as well as the previous one)? Would appreciate if someone from Microsoft could answer.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/quick_thoughts/archive/2015/01/08/monetization-with-pubcenter-ads-part-1-creating-app-id-and-ad-unit-id.aspx) is a link that shows how the experience used to be. But now when I log onto pubcenter there is no button like below to monetize a new app:
[image]

and dev.windows.com does not offer any option to select ad size unlike the past experience below:
[image]

Comment: adding a link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186437.aspx. Note  You will no longer be able to create ad units or new app promotion campaigns in pubCenter. For information on how to create ad units in Dev Center, see Monetize with ads. For information on how to create app promotion campaigns in Dev Center, see Create an ad campaign for your app.

Comment: adding another link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt628523(v=msads.30).aspx#windows160x600

Comment: one more (final) https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/10/08/new-advertising-features-and-walkthrough-of-using-microsoft-ads-and-mediation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one does not have to declare the ad size with the new dev.windows.com portal. It is sufficient to create a new ad unit and use it like below (illustration is for WinJS using MSAdvertising SDK for windows 8.1). However one issue I ran into is that my app did not start serving ads until after 1 week. Needless to say, that was pretty annoying and a bad experience for customers.

```
<div id="myAd" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; right: 0px; width: 160px; height: 600px; z-index: 1"
         data-win-control="MicrosoftNSJS.Advertising.AdControl"
         data-win-options="{applicationId: 'XXX', adUnitId: 'XXX'}">
    </div>
```